# Optimising format! to nop if its result isn't used

Tags: rust

Suppose I have a simple logging trait like this:

```rust
pub trait Log {
  fn log(&mut self, _message: &str) {}
}
```

I might write a function that uses it like this:

```rust
pub fn output_int(x: i32, log: &mut impl Log) {
  log.log(&format!("Writing value: {}", x));
  
  // Do something with x
}
```

However this has a flaw: even though I used static dispatch, and build with `--release`, the call to `format!()` is not optimised away ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3bcKax)).

It is possible to fix it using a `should_log()`-style method and then it compiles to nothing:

```rust
pub trait Log {
  fn log(&mut self, _message: &str) {}
  fn should_log(&self) -> bool { false }
}

pub fn output_int(x: i32, log: &mut impl Log) {
  if log.should_log() {
    log.log(&format!("Writing value: {}", x));
  }
  
  // Do something with x
}

struct NopLog {}

impl Log for NopLog {}

pub fn main() {
  let mut log = NopLog{};
  output_int(3, &mut log);
}
```

However this doesn't feel very ergonomic. The best workaround I can think of is to make a macro like this:

```rust
macro_rules! log {
  ($log:ident, $($arg:tt)*) => {
    if $log.should_log() {
      $log.log(&format!($($arg)*));
    }
  };
}

pub fn output_int(x: i32, log: &mut impl Log) {
  log!(log, "Writing value: {}", x);
  
  // Do something with x
}
```

It works, but still feels a little hacky. I just wanted to check - am I missing some obvious simpler solution to calling `format!()` while also allowing it to be optimised to a nop?

Comment: How about accepting a closure instead of a string as the message, so you can write `log.log(|| &format!("Writing value: {}", x))`?

Comment: Oh yeah... I know I was missing something obvious! I'm pretty sure that's how the standard library usually deals with this issue too. Thanks!

Comment: @SvenMarnach Note that this particular example won't work, since the reference would become dangling once the closure returns. I'd suggest something like `impl FnOnce() -> impl Into<Cow<'static, str>>`, such that borh a literal and an allocated `String` can be returned.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Of course, you are right. I didn't really look at what I copied from the question. :)

Comment: The reason this is not optimized away is that the call to `format` is happening in `output_int`, before being passed as an argument, and its behavior (think panics) is observable there, regardless of whether the return value is actually used.

Comment: How is the behaviour observable in `output_int()`? If everything gets inlined, the compiler should theoretically be able to figure out that the value isn't used.

Comment: @SvenMarnach it would also have to realize that `format!` is pure, which requires some powerful global analysis, especially since it calls formatting traits on arbitrary values.

Comment: @NieDzejkob If it _could_ inline everything, the compiler would just need to look at the data flow in the inlined code. It's very well possible that the format machinery is too complex to inline. My point is just that it's not possible to tell a priori that the compiler won't be able to optimise this.

Comment: AFAIK the format machinery also uses dynamic dispatch somewhere, which makes it difficult or even impossible to inline completely.

Comment: `format!()` is never optimized away AFAIK: https://godbolt.org/z/KnvzKn. This is because `alloc::fmt::format()` is not optimized away. Maybe it's worth opening an issue about that? It's not a bug but I think it could be improved.

Comment: However since the best solution would probably just be const propagation, I think this probably won't be resolved until `String::new` is const, which I think is blocked on the debate over const traits/functions.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the solution here is to use `impl Display` or `&dyn Display` (if you need object safety) instead of `&str`. That way, the laziness is inherent to the type, and you can pass a type that only lazily performs formatting on-demand. You can then use something like [`format_args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format_args.html) or [`lazy_format`](https://docs.rs/lazy_format/latest/lazy_format/) to actually construct your lazy formatting logic; both of them will create an opaque object that only runs the formatting logic on-demand.

That is to say, your logging trait becomes:

```rust
pub trait Log {
  fn log(&mut self, message: impl Display) {}
}
```

And your callsite becomes:

```
pub fn output_int(x: i32, log: &mut impl Log) {
  log.log(format_args!("Writing value: {x}"));
  
  // Do something with x
}
```